# Python's string count function doesn't use regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, function

when trying to count all letters in a string using the count function and the regex [A-Za-z], it returns a a value of zero.

For instance:

```
string="Hi, everybody. Let's dance!"

string.count('[A-Za-z]') ## prints 0
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Python's `count` doesn't accept a regex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm

Comment: @cdarke, `len()`, by itself, would also include the punctuation and spaces, which is not wanted.

Comment: Title says it all...

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expressions:

```
len(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', string))
```

Comment: Better in my opinion: `len(c for c in string if c.isalpha())`

Comment: @brianpck likely faster too for most cases... (no compile time of pattern)

Comment: A for-loop in python is probably slower than a reg-ex written in C.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in brianpcks comment, there are alternatives that do not require using regular expressions:

```
len(c for c in string if c.isalpha())
```

or

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
len(c for c in string if c in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Although these alternatives might be slower in CPython, your mileage may vary using other Python implementations (especially PyPy, who's JIT can optimize python loops very well).

As always, if speed is a concern, benchmark both approaches in your environment before deciding which to use.

Answer (score -1):

Because that's not how count works,look at this link [count](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm)

In that statement you are telling how much substrings of '[A-Za-z]' are in string 
if you want to count all the letters in a string use len()

Comment: `len` returns the length of a string, *not* the letters in a string. `len('   ') == 1`